# XML Literals LINQ - use variables in Enumerable.Range(int, int)

Tags: linq, xml-literals

Help me please - how can I use in this code:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = _
    New XDocument( _
    New XElement("root"))
    doc.Root.Add(From i In Enumerable.Range(0, 10) _
                 Select New XElement("foo", i))


                 Dim doc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0"?>
                       <root>
                           <values>
                               <%= From i In Enumerable.Range(1, 3) Select <value>
                                                                               <%= cells(i, 1).Value %>
                                                                           </value> %>
                           </values>

                       </root>
```

here in stead of numbers variables? Enumerable.Range(1, 3) something like this:

```
Dim iCount = 5
    Enumerable.Range(1, iCount)
```

I have an error if use like this - 'iCount' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 0):

now all ok but here there is an error on this Row: (...) == "y"

```
..... 
</Header>
                                            <Request>
                                                <%= From i In Enumerable.Range(1, LastRow) Select
                                                    <%= If(LCase(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, 25).Value) == "y",
                                                        <ID>
                                                            <%= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value %>
                                                        </ID>,
                                                        Nothing)
                                                    %>
                                                %>
                                            </Request>
                                        </RequestMessage>
                                    </soapenv:Body>
                                </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: `==` is for C#. In VB it would be `=`